# Create SQL db structure from xpath

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I am trying to dump the contents of an xml file in to a sql table (relational format).

In the past, I have used dataset.readxml but have had some issues with it while handling many to many relationships.

So I took an approach as follows, create a unique list of xpath expression for all the elements and attributes in the xml file and then using these expressions create a sql db structure to persist this data.

I wanted to create this feature as a dynamic implementation to handle any xml.

Let's say I have an xml file and the unique Xpath are as follows

```
/movie/MovieId[1]  
/movie/MovieName[1]  

/movie/cast[1]  
/movie/cast[1]/name[1]  
/movie/cast[1]/name[2]  
/movie/cast[1]/name[3]/@rolename 

/movie/description[1]  
/movie/directors[1]  
/movie/directors[1]/name[1]  
/movie/directors[1]/name[1]  
/movie/directors[1]/name[2]  
/movie/directors[1]/name[3]  
/movie/releasedate[1]  
/movie/releasedate[1]/@reldatetestatt  
/movie/runtime[1]
```

I would like the table structure to be created as follows:

TableName: Movie
Columns: MovieId, MovieName, description, releasedate, reldatetestatt, runtime

TableName: Cast
Columns: MovieId, name, rolename

TableName: Directors
Columns: MovieId, name

Sample Xml for your reference:

```
var xml = @"<movies>
   <movie>
   <MovieId>277345</MovieId>
   <MovieName>The Life and Passion of Jesus Christ</MovieName>
    <description>The Gospels of the New Testament.</description>
    <runtime>44</runtime>
    <releasedate reldatetestatt='testattribute'>3/26/1904 12:00:00 AM</releasedate>
    <directors>
        <name>Lucien Nonguet</name>
        <name>Ferdinand Zecca</name>
        <name>Ferdinand Zecca 2</name>
    </directors>
    <cast>
        <name rolename='test'>Madame Moreau</name>
        <name>Monsieur Moreau</name>
    </cast>
    </movie>
</movies>";
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? Do you want à full script? Some advices?

Comment: A psuedocode would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Talend Open Studio](http://www.talend.com/download.php) (aka Jaster ETL). It will happily take xml and fill a database. You can do it from the UI or export the "job" as independent java code.

Comment: Thank You, KCD. I am looking for a .net based solution.